# Difference between useRef() and { }

Tags: react-hooks

I am reading about `useRef()` and playing with simple examples.

What surprises me is that whenever I replace

```
const MyComponent = ({value}) => {
  const myRef = useRef();
  [...]
```

with

```
const MyComponent = ({value}) => {
  const myRef = {};
  [...]
```

a component works in the same way.
Do you know any example that would show the real advantage of the hook?

Comment: You're not supposed to use `myRef` directly. You're only supposed to use the memoized value on the property [`myRef.current`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). A brief inspection at the documentation should answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try

```
  const myRef = {};
  //..
  // at some point e.g. in click handler do:
  myRef.a = 123;
```

Now trigger a rerender of the component and log value of `myRef`, you will see the change you made above will be lost on the next render. *On each render a new `myRef` is created*. The value returned by `useRef` on the other hand is persisted for the full lifetime of the component.

Comment: You are right. I must have used a too complicated example. Using the following one you can see the difference: 
`// const myRef = useRef({});
  const myRef= {};

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Updating ...');
    if (!myRef.current) {
      myRef.current = 100;
    }
    console.log(myRef.current++);
  });`